# Should you accept the best answer for problems that can't be solved yet?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

Many questions I've asked can't be solved in the near future, and since it's become so important to accept answers (courtesy of the accept rate), should I just accept any good answer even though the problem isn't solved by it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chill.

If the answers on your question slate don't suit or solve your needs, don't arbitrarily accept any answer just for the sake of a higher accept rate. 70% and higher is good, but you don't need to shoot for the 100% moon.

Wait some on the lingering questions, it's fine, really it is. Not all questions have to be solved and green-boxed out of vision within a day.

If the information landscape around that question changes, you may see an acceptable answer pop up. An answerer that would have otherwise not seen or bothered with your question if you did accept one willy-nilly.

Comment: "An answerer that would have otherwise not seen or bothered with your question if you did accept any random answer" -- correct.

Answer (score 4):

No. The accept rate isn't that important.

Jeff [has said](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)

> It is considered good manners to
> accept answers on your questions,
> eventually, but accepting answers is
> not required. I personally consider
> anything at 70% or over quite good,
> meaning you accept answers on 7 out of
> 10 questions that you ask. **There are
> certainly cases where you don’t get an
> answer you like, or the question is
> inherently unanswerable.**

(emphasis mine)

Although one might question the validity of questions who can't be solved right now. They suspiciously look like subjective discussions.

Comment: What about if you ask a question like "Can I do X with software Y?" and you get a bunch of answers that amount to "No, you can't".  It's not subjective, it's just that software Y doesn't support what you want to do.

Comment: That's an answer, and should be accepted.

Comment: Ok, let's rephrase that then.  What if you ask a question like "How do I do X with software Y" where X is something you reasonably expect any software similar to Y to be able to do.  If somebody says "you can't" that might not be an acceptable answer.  First, it may actually be possible, but the method of doing it is really obscure, or else requires looking at the problem differently.  It might be possible but require working around some kind of bug in the software as well.