# What is the best procedure for a question that wasn't answered well but has an upvote?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

For example [PIL: Image resizing : Algorithm similar to firefox's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386400/pil-image-resizing-algorithm-similar-to-firefoxs/1386414#1386414) . I got one answer, but it didn't solve my problem and it has an upvote. This means my questions won't appear in the unanswered section so it won't get much traffic past this point.

Do I close the question? Accept his answer? Post a response that it didn't work? Downvote him? Re-ask the requestion?

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't answer your question, then explain why (either in a comment on the answer itself, or by editing your question and leaving a comment).

Then down-vote it.

Answer (score 4):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> ### What if I don't get a good answer?
>
> In order to get good answers, you have
>   to put some effort into the question.
>   Edit your question to provide status
>   and progress updates. Document your
>   own continued efforts to answer your
>   question. This will naturally bump
>   your question and get more people
>   interested in it.
>
> If, after two days, you still don't
>   have an answer you like, you can offer
>   a bounty. Slice off a bit of your own
>   hard-earned reputation -- anywhere
>   from 50 to 500 -- and attach it to the
>   question as a bounty. We'll even throw
>   in 50 reputation to sweeten the deal.
>   The bountied question will appear with
>   a special icon in all question lists,
>   and it will also be visible on the
>   [home page Featured tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured).
>
> Once initiated, the bounty period
>   lasts seven days. If you mark an
>   accepted answer, your bounty is
>   awarded to the answerer (do note that
>   accepted bounty answers are permanent
>   and cannot be changed). If you do not
>   accept an answer in seven days, the
>   top voted answer will automatically
>   become the accepted answer, and half
>   your bounty will be awarded to that
>   answer. You will always give up the
>   amount of reputation specified in the
>   bounty, so if you start a bounty, be
>   sure to follow up and accept the best
>   answer!
>
> Of course, bounty awards, like all
>   accepted answers, are immune to the
>   daily reputation cap and community
>   wiki mode.

Answer (score 3):

If it isnt correct, then don't say it is.

Unresolved questions do get prodded and poked automaticly every now and then to get more attention.

**Edit:** I was looking for another question that would have been fantastic to quote, but I can't find it. Instead, take a look at [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20638/should-you-accept-the-best-answer-for-problems-that-cant-be-solved-yet)

> If the answers on your question slate don't suit or solve your needs, don't arbitrarily accept any answer just for the sake of a higher accept rate. 70% and higher is good, but you don't need to shoot for the 100% moon.
>
> Wait some on the lingering questions, it's fine, really it is. Not all questions have to be solved and green-boxed out of vision within a day.
>
> If the information landscape around that question changes, you may see an acceptable answer pop up. An answerer that would have otherwise not seen or bothered with your question if you did accept one willy-nilly.

Comment: Isn't an upvoted answer considered resolved?

Comment: @Paul - No. It just indicates that the community agrees with the answer and it is most likely the solution for the problem. It helps avoid the same answer being posted 20 times.

Comment: Paul: I once asked a question on SO about bubble sorting. After about one week, there was a clear 'winner' in who the community though was the correct answer. It had nearly twice the number of  upvotes of the second highest question.

To bad that question was fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing Paul is referring to the unanswered tab

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the unanswered tab, which is where I personally go to find people that need help. A single upvote won't show it in there.